# Plane graph combinatorially isomorphic to one with all edges straight

Tags: graph-theory

I have this problem. I have to show that every plane graph is combinatorially isomorphic to a plane graph whose edges are all straight. I Also have an hint that says to give a plane triangulation and construct inductively a graph theoretically isomorphic with all edges straight. Can some one give me an idea or sketch of the proof. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Fary's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry's_theorem) and here is the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry's_theorem#Proof)